# How can the schema of solr be integrated with node?

Tags: node.js, apache, solr, lucene

I have implemented the SOLR schema.xml and it is working good.
But I don't understand why it is not getting integrated with my express app?
Means, the suggesters and filters all which I have defined is not getting applied to the express node app?
I am using solr-client package for this purpose.

`

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
      <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>      
      <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
      <str name="field">fname</str>
      <str name="weightField">price</str>
      <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text</str>
      <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="suggester">
      <str name="name">altSuggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>      
      <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
      <str name="field">lname</str>
      <str name="weightField">price</str>
      <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text</str>
      <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>

  <requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" 
                  startup="lazy" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="suggest">true</str>
      <str name="suggest.dictionary">mySuggester</str>
      <str name="suggest.dictionary">altSuggester</str>
      <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
      <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>`
```

This is my suggester which i have applied on table 'fname' and 'lname'.
My doubt is, this suggester works pretty well when I query from solr admin. But when I run client.search.q(query), this suggesters seems not implemented in my express(node) app.

Comment: It would help if you could provide some code snippets.

Comment: You usually call a specific, defined request handler or select a query type (`defType`) to tell Solr what you want to achieve and how your query is defined. How are you trying to use Solr now, and what endpoint / query do you want to perform?

Comment: This is my suggester which i have applied on table 'fname' and 'lname'.
My doubt is, this suggester works pretty well when I query from solr admin. But when I run client.search.q(query), this suggesters seems not implemented in my express(node) app.